# Unable to deploy mule application on on prem

Tags: azure-devops, mule, anypoint-platform

I am trying to deploy an Mule application to On prem using Azure pipeline, below is the Azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
    batch: true
    branches: 
        include: 
        - develop
    paths: 
        exclude: 
        - azure-pipelines.yml

variables:

- group: Build-Variable-Group
- name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
  value: $(HOME)/.m2/repository
- name: MAVEN_OPTS
  value: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'
- name: vmImageName
  value: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Verify 
  displayName: Verification
  jobs:
  - job: VerifyApi
    displayName: Verify raml 
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: api folder 
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $Folder = '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/main/resources/api'
          "Test to see if folder [$Folder]  exists"
          if (Test-Path -Path $Folder) {
            echo "$Folder"
            "Path exists!"
          } else {
              "RAML doesn't exit in the GITHUB repository"
              exit 1 
          }
          
- stage: Build 
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildApiManager
    displayName: Build API Manager
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: CacheBeta@0
      inputs:
        key: pom.xml
        path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
      displayName: Cache Maven local Repo

    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: settingsxml
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'settings.xml'

    - task: Powershell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.m2"
            Copy-Item -Force "$(settingsxml.secureFilePath)" "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml"


    
    - task: Maven@3
      displayName: Deploy API Manager
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        goals: 'clean package -Papi-Danypoint.user=${anypoint.uname} -Danypoint.password=${anypoint.pass} -DorgId=${org.id} -Dversion=${apiVersion} -DenvId=${environment} -DdeploymentType=hybrid -Dpackaging=pom -DassetId=${app.name} -Dpolicy=${policy1}'
        
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: DeployArtifacts
    displayName: Deploy & Publish Artifacts
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: CacheBeta@0
      inputs:
        key: pom.xml
        path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
      displayName: Cache Maven local Repo

    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: settingsxml
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'settings.xml'
    - task: Powershell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.m2"
            Copy-Item -Force "$(settingsxml.secureFilePath)" "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml"
    - task: Maven@3
      displayName: Deploy Runtime Manager 
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        goals: 'clean install deploy $(MAVEN_OPTS) -DmuleDeploy -Dserver=$(server) -Denvironment=$(environment) -Dworkers=$(workers) -DworkerType=$(workerType) -Dapp.runtime=$(app.runtime) -Dapp.name=$(app.name)'
```

Blow is the error I am  getting in Azure pipeline log

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project clx-mule-sftp-sapi: Failed to deploy [/home/vsts/work/1/s/target/clx-mule-sftp-sapi-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And below is the error which i am getting in Runtime manager log

```
Worker(3.81.37.13): Your application has failed with exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.mulesoft.ch.services.agent.muleAgent.MuleAgentException: {"type":"class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"There was an error on the Mule Runtime while deploying the application clx-mule-sftp-sapi-pdv2. Error: Domain 'domain-sys-api-1.0.1-mule-domain' has to be deployed in order to deploy Application 'clx-mule-sftp-sapi-pdv2'. DomainNotFoundException: The domain 'domain-sys-api-1.0.1-mule-domain' was not found. Available domains: [[default]]"}
```

We are able to deploy in cloudhub with same code but while trying to deploy in on-prem using same code ( changed the variables as per env ) it is showing error.

Comment: Please share the Mule Maven Plugin configuration from the pom.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly indicates that the application depends on a domain:

```
Error: Domain 'domain-sys-api-1.0.1-mule-domain' has to be deployed in order to deploy Application 'clx-mule-sftp-sapi-pdv2'
```

You need to deploy the domain first before attempting to deploy the application. The steps are similar to deploy an application. See the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/deploy-on-premises#deploy-a-domain) for details.

It is not possible that you deployed the same application to CloudHub since it doesn't support domains. I guess that you are referring to reusing the same deployment model. You need to understand the difference in the features between the different deployment targets.